# Is there a way to request multiple distinct resources in parallel using URLSession.shared.dataTask

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession, nsurlsessiondatatask

I found this piece of code here on how to download images simultaneously without any breakages,

```
    func loadImageRobsAnswer(with urlString: String?) {
    // cancel prior task, if any


    weak var oldTask = currentTask
    currentTask = nil
    oldTask?.cancel()



    // reset imageview's image

    self.image = nil

    // allow supplying of `nil` to remove old image and then return immediately

    guard let urlString = urlString else { return }

    // check cache



    if let cachedImage = DataCache.shared.object(forKey: urlString) {



        self.transition(toImage: cachedImage as? UIImage)
        //self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    // download

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    currentURL = url

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
        self?.currentTask = nil



        if let error = error {


            if (error as NSError).domain == NSURLErrorDomain && (error as NSError).code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
                return
            }

            print(error)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data, let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
            print("unable to extract image")
            return
        }

        DataCache.shared.saveObject(object: downloadedImage, forKey: urlString)

        if url == self?.currentURL {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self?.transition(toImage: downloadedImage)

            }
        }
    }

    // save and start new task

    currentTask = task
    task.resume()
}
```

However this code is used in a UIImageView extension,

```
    public extension UIImageView {
  private static var taskKey = 0
  private static var urlKey = 0

  private var currentTask: URLSessionTask? {
    get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIImageView.taskKey) as? URLSessionTask }
    set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIImageView.taskKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC) }
}

private var currentURL: URL? {
    get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &UIImageView.urlKey) as? URL }
    set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &UIImageView.urlKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC) }
}}}
```

This is how i have tried to make this code dynamic so it wont be limited to only an UIImageView but can be used  to download multiple resources.

```
class DataRequest {
private static var taskKey = 0
private static var urlKey = 0
static let shared = DataRequest()
    typealias ImageDataCompletion = (_ image: UIImage?, _ error: Error? ) -> Void

private var currentTask: URLSessionTask? {
    get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &DataRequest.taskKey) as? URLSessionTask }
    set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &DataRequest.taskKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC) }
}

private var currentURL: URL? {
    get { return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &DataRequest.urlKey) as? URL }
    set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &DataRequest.urlKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC) }
}


 func downloadImage(with urlString: String?, completion: @escaping ImageDataCompletion) {



    weak var oldTask = currentTask
    currentTask = nil
    oldTask?.cancel()





    guard let urlString = urlString else { return }





    if let cachedImage = DataCache.shared.object(forKey: urlString) {
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
        completion(cachedImage as? UIImage ,nil)
        }
       // self.transition(toImage: cachedImage as? UIImage)
        //self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    // download

    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    currentURL = url

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
        self?.currentTask = nil



        if let error = error {


            if (error as NSError).domain == NSURLErrorDomain && (error as NSError).code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
                return
            }

             completion(nil,nil)
            return
        }

        guard let data = data, let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
            print("unable to extract image")
            return
        }

        DataCache.shared.saveObject(object: downloadedImage, forKey: urlString)

        if url == self?.currentURL {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                 completion(downloadedImage ,nil)

            }
        }
    }

    // save and start new task

    currentTask = task
    task.resume()
}
```

So that i can now use it in an UIImageview extension like this

```
    extension UIImageView {
       func setImage(url: String?) {

    self.image = nil
    DataRequest.shared.downloadImage(with: url) { (image, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = image


        }
    }

}
    }
```

Concluding using my approach on a UICollectionView is displaying the wrong images into a cell and duplicating ,How do i prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> Is there a way to request multiple distinct resources in parallel using `URLSession.shared.dataTask`

By default, it does perform requests in parallel.

Let’s step back for a second: In your prior question, you were asking how to implement a Kingfisher-like `UIImageView` extension. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56096365/1271826), I mentioned using `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject` to achieve that. But in your question here, you’ve taken that associated object logic and put it in your `DataRequest` object.

Your thought process, to pull the asynchronous image retrieval logic out of the `UIImageView` is a good idea: You may want to request images for buttons. You might a general “fetch image asynchronously” routine, completely separate from any UIKit objects. So abstracting the network layer code out of the extension is an excellent idea.

But the whole idea behind asynchronous image retrieval `UIImageView`/`UIButton` extensions is that we want a UIKit control where not only can it perform asynchronous requests, but that if the cell with the control is reused, that it will cancel the prior asynchronous request (if any) before starting the next one. That way, if we scroll quickly down to images 80 through 99, the requests for cells 0 through 79 will be canceled, and the visible images won’t get backlogged behind all these old image requests.

But to achieve that, that means that the control needs some way to keep track of the prior request for that reused cell somehow. And because we can’t add stored properties in a `UIImageView` extension, that’s why we use the `objc_getAssociatedObject` and `objc_setAssociatedObject` pattern. But that has to be in the image view.

Unfortunately, in your code above, the associated object is in your `DataRequest` object. First, as I’ve tried to outline, the whole idea is that the image view must keep track of the prior request for that control. Putting this “keep track of the prior request” inside the `DataRequest` object defeats that purpose. Second, it’s worth noting that you don’t need associated objects in your own types, like `DataRequest`. You’d just have a stored property. You only need to go through this associated object silliness when extending another type, such as `UIImageView`.

Below, is a quick example that I whipped together showing a `UIImageView` extension for asynchronous image retrieval. Note, this doesn’t have the abstraction of the network code out of the extension, but do note that the associated object logic to keep track of the prior request must remain with the extension.

```
extension UIImageView {
    private static var taskKey: Void?

    private static let imageProcessingQueue = DispatchQueue(label: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier! + ".imageprocessing", attributes: .concurrent)

    private var savedTask: URLSessionTask? {
        get { objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &Self.taskKey) as? URLSessionTask }
        set { objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &Self.taskKey, newValue, .OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN) }
    }

    /// Set image asynchronously.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - url: `URL` for image resource.
    ///   - placeholder: `UIImage` of placeholder image. If not supplied, `image` will be set to `nil` while request is underway.
    ///   - shouldResize: Whether the image should be scaled to the size of the image view. Defaults to `true`.

    func setImage(_ url: URL, placeholder: UIImage? = nil, shouldResize: Bool = true) {
        savedTask?.cancel()
        savedTask = nil

        image = placeholder
        if let image = ImageCache.shared[url] {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                    self.image = image
                }, completion: nil)
            }
            return
        }

        var task: URLSessionTask!
        let size = bounds.size * UIScreen.main.scale
        task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            guard
                error == nil,
                let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                (200..<300) ~= httpResponse.statusCode,
                let data = data
            else {
                return
            }

            UIImageView.imageProcessingQueue.async { [weak self] in
                var image = UIImage(data: data)
                if shouldResize {
                    image = image?.scaledAspectFit(to: size)
                }

                ImageCache.shared[url] = image

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    guard
                        let self = self,
                        let savedTask = self.savedTask,
                        savedTask.taskIdentifier == task.taskIdentifier
                    else {
                        return
                    }
                    self.savedTask = nil

                    UIView.transition(with: self, duration: 0.1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                        self.image = image
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        savedTask = task
    }
}

class ImageCache {
    static let shared = ImageCache()

    private let cache = NSCache<NSURL, UIImage>()
    private var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

    init() {
        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIApplication.didReceiveMemoryWarningNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.cache.removeAllObjects()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(observer!)
    }

    subscript(url: URL) -> UIImage? {
        get {
            return cache.object(forKey: url as NSURL)
        }

        set {
            if let data = newValue {
                cache.setObject(data, forKey: url as NSURL)
            } else {
                cache.removeObject(forKey: url as NSURL)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my resizing routine:

```
extension UIImage {
    
    /// Resize the image to be the required size, stretching it as needed.
    ///
    /// - parameter newSize:      The new size of the image.
    /// - parameter contentMode:  The `UIView.ContentMode` to be applied when resizing image.
    ///                           Either `.scaleToFill`, `.scaleAspectFill`, or `.scaleAspectFit`.
    ///
    /// - returns:                Return `UIImage` of resized image.
    
    func scaled(to newSize: CGSize, contentMode: UIView.ContentMode = .scaleToFill) -> UIImage? {
        switch contentMode {
        case .scaleToFill:
            return filled(to: newSize)

        case .scaleAspectFill, .scaleAspectFit:
            let horizontalRatio = size.width  / newSize.width
            let verticalRatio   = size.height / newSize.height
            
            let ratio: CGFloat!
            if contentMode == .scaleAspectFill {
                ratio = min(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
            } else {
                ratio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
            }
            
            let sizeForAspectScale = CGSize(width: size.width / ratio, height: size.height / ratio)
            let image = filled(to: sizeForAspectScale)
            let doesAspectFitNeedCropping = contentMode == .scaleAspectFit && (newSize.width > sizeForAspectScale.width || newSize.height > sizeForAspectScale.height)
            if contentMode == .scaleAspectFill || doesAspectFitNeedCropping {
                let subRect = CGRect(
                    x: floor((sizeForAspectScale.width - newSize.width) / 2.0),
                    y: floor((sizeForAspectScale.height - newSize.height) / 2.0),
                    width: newSize.width,
                    height: newSize.height)
                return image?.cropped(to: subRect)
            }
            return image

        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    /// Resize the image to be the required size, stretching it as needed.
    ///
    /// - parameter newSize:   The new size of the image.
    ///
    /// - returns:             Resized `UIImage` of resized image.
    
    func filled(to newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.opaque = false
        format.scale = scale
        
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize, format: format).image { _ in
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize))
        }
    }
    
    /// Crop the image to be the required size.
    ///
    /// - parameter bounds:    The bounds to which the new image should be cropped.
    ///
    /// - returns:             Cropped `UIImage`.
    
    func cropped(to bounds: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        // if bounds is entirely within image, do simple CGImage `cropping` ...
        
        if CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size).contains(bounds) {
            return cgImage?.cropping(to: bounds * scale).flatMap {
                UIImage(cgImage: $0, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
            }
        }
        
        // ... otherwise, manually render whole image, only drawing what we need
        
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.opaque = false
        format.scale = scale
        
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size, format: format).image { _ in
            let origin = CGPoint(x: -bounds.minX, y: -bounds.minY)
            draw(in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
        }
    }
    
    /// Resize the image to fill the rectange of the specified size, preserving the aspect ratio, trimming if needed.
    ///
    /// - parameter newSize:   The new size of the image.
    ///
    /// - returns:             Return `UIImage` of resized image.
    
    func scaledAspectFill(to newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return scaled(to: newSize, contentMode: .scaleAspectFill)
    }
    
    /// Resize the image to fit within the required size, preserving the aspect ratio, with no trimming taking place.
    ///
    /// - parameter newSize:   The new size of the image.
    ///
    /// - returns:             Return `UIImage` of resized image.
    
    func scaledAspectFit(to newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
        return scaled(to: newSize, contentMode: .scaleAspectFit)
    }
    
    /// Create smaller image from `Data`
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - data: The image `Data`.
    ///   - maxSize: The maximum edge size.
    ///   - scale: The scale of the image (defaults to device scale if 0 or omitted.
    /// - Returns: The scaled `UIImage`.
    
    class func thumbnail(from data: Data, maxSize: CGFloat, scale: CGFloat = 0) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return thumbnail(from: imageSource, maxSize: maxSize, scale: scale)
    }
    
    /// Create smaller image from `URL`
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - data: The image file URL.
    ///   - maxSize: The maximum edge size.
    ///   - scale: The scale of the image (defaults to device scale if 0 or omitted.
    /// - Returns: The scaled `UIImage`.
    
    class func thumbnail(from fileURL: URL, maxSize: CGFloat, scale: CGFloat = 0) -> UIImage? {
        guard let imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(fileURL as CFURL, nil) else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return thumbnail(from: imageSource, maxSize: maxSize, scale: scale)
    }

    private class func thumbnail(from imageSource: CGImageSource, maxSize: CGFloat, scale: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        let scale = scale == 0 ? UIScreen.main.scale : scale
        let options: [NSString: Any] = [
            kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize: maxSize * scale,
            kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: true
        ]
        if let scaledImage = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(imageSource, 0, options as CFDictionary) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: scaledImage, scale: scale, orientation: .up)
        }
        return nil
    }

}

extension CGSize {
    static func * (lhs: CGSize, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(width: lhs.width * rhs, height: lhs.height * rhs)
    }
}

extension CGPoint {
    static func * (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        CGPoint(x: lhs.x * rhs, y: lhs.y * rhs)
    }
}

extension CGRect {
    static func * (lhs: CGRect, rhs: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        CGRect(origin: lhs.origin * rhs, size: lhs.size * rhs)
    }
}
```

---

That having been said, we really should constrain our concurrent requests to something reasonable (4-6 at a time) so that they don’t try to start until the prior requests are done (or are canceled) to avoid timeouts. The typical solution is wrapping the requests with asynchronous `Operation` subclasses, add them to an operation queue, and constrain the `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to whatever value you choose.

Comment: But URLSession will keep concurrent requests reasonable automatically.

Comment: @Rob Do you always have to put the image download task in a UIImageView extension ? , what if i want to extract the  setImage function into a class with a different completion handler with  datatypes of Json or Strings  and still  avoid  requests and responses from being scattered    around .

Comment: @matt yeah, but it tops out at a fairly low number and you can start to hit timeout limits on the latter requests in edge case scenarios. And I think a queue for requests is better than increasing max counts and/or timeouts. But to each his own.

Comment: I am researching on how to wrap my requests with asynchronous Operation subclasses, as you suggested.

Comment: @BigFire - not only _can_ you pull out the requests from the extension, but IMHO, you _should._ But the key point is that this associated object stuff should be in the `UIImageView` extension, though (because the whole idea is that the image view must keep track of the last request for that image view, cancel it if it’s still underway before starting another request, etc.). By putting the associated object in your request object, you’ve defeated the purpose of what we were trying to do.

Comment: Oh i see i've now understood the use of the associated object stuff ,to track my request in general i have to look into the Operation queue but not associated object .Thank you

Comment: @Rob you can simplify your UIImage instance methods using UIImage `imageRendererFormat` instance property https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1649497-imagerendererformat `UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size, format: imageRendererFormat)`

Comment: @Rob do you have any sample code or links on your approach of wrapping URLSessionTasks in an OperationQueue?

Comment: @LeoDabus - actually, which renderer format option were you thinking of?

Comment: you can use `imageRendererFormat` instead of   `let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        format.opaque = false
        format.scale = scale`
`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42098390/swift-png-image-being-saved-with-incorrect-orientation/42098812#42098812

Comment: @LeoDabus Oh, I get your point. But if aspect fit, though, I personally don't want to use `format.opaque` of the original image.

Comment: @BigFire This is URLSessionDownloadTask`, but the idea is the same as it would be for data tasks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322851/1271826

Comment: @Rob , Yes the link was helpful